# Wood filler between old and new hardwood strip flooring?

Tags: flooring, floor, hardwood-floor, hardwood

House was built in 1983 and had 2-3/4" strip flooring on most of the main floor. When we bought the house in Winter of 2020, we had the two remaining rooms stripped of carpet and had hardwoods to match (closely) installed. Now that it's that time of year, we are noticing a few things.

For the most part, the strip flooring is tightly coupled. However, in the kitchen near the dishwasher and in the powder room, the strips have gaps. Now I am aware this is likely seasonal, humidity in our area generally around 60-70% and then suddenly dropped to 35% (yay nail pops as well), but it has revealed a large amount of "gap filler" in these two rooms. Additionally, the new hardwoods have a couple of spots where the installers used this same putty like filler.

So I have a couple of questions:

1. Should I cut away the old cracked fills and replace?
2. Is it common for needing gap filler on fresh installs?
3. If not #1 what is my alternative?

Comment: Is this engineered wood, with snap-joint tongue & groove? Is it free to move or is it 'nailed' to the sub-structure? Do you have expansion space around the edges?

Comment: @Tetsujin they are tongue and groove. Most have their ends overlapped with trim so I’m not sure how much space beyond they have to flex.

Comment: Lift the trim. The trick is to have the floor float as one solid unit, capable of expanding & contracting without pulling apart or buckling as it hits the walls - hence should not be fixed down anywhere & needs to be on an underlay layer that will allow this. The trim attaches to the walls not the floor so this process happens invisibly.